# How do I remove a PayPal account from being the default payment method in eBay?

Tags: account-management, paypal, ebay

When I go to pay for an item in eBay, the default payment method is the wrong PayPal account.  I'd like to unlink it, but the best instructions I can find say the following:

1. After logging in to eBay, hover over your name in the upper left corner.
2. In the dropdown that should appear, click Account Settings.
3. On the left side, there should be a box titled something like "My eBay Views" with a section "My Account" and under that, "Paypal Account."  Click that ("Paypal Account").
4. There should be some text indicating what PayPal account is currently linked (by e-mail address, with username elided), and a small link to unlink the account.  Click that.

However, when I go to that page, the correct PayPal account is listed.  Even if I unlink it, log out, clear cache and cookies, etc., when I log back in to eBay to pay for an item, it's got that same incorrect PayPal account as the default method.  It doesn't matter how many times I do this.

How do I get rid of the incorrect PayPal account as my default payment method?

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 steps are the same.  In step 3, under "My Account," there should also be a link which reads "Personal Information."  Click that.  Then on the right there are sections:

- Account Information
- Email and Contact Information
- Financial Information
- Security Information

Under "Financial Information" there may be the following options:

- Automatic payment method
- Checkout saved payment methods
- Reimbursement payment method
- Charity payment method
- PayPal Account

The second section, "Checkout saved payment method," should list the incorrect linked Paypal account.  On the right side, there should be a "Remove" link.  Click that.